# Python : Unexpected spaces between Tkinter frames

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, space, tk-toolkit

I'm working on a wizard and as the title says unexpected spaces appeared.

I tried to stick cyan and yellow frame to their respective North, West, South and East borders.
Without the left frame (element + listbox + uniform font) it seems to work as I expected however when adding it, it creates theses grey gaps.

Here's the code and a preview:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

Mafenetre = Tk()

frame3_root = Frame(Mafenetre, padx=10, pady=10)

frame3_frame_list = Frame(Mafenetre, bg='red')
frame3_frame_list.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, sticky=W + E + N + S)
Label(frame3_frame_list, text="Elements").pack(padx=20, pady=20)
frame3_listbox_font = Listbox(frame3_frame_list, exportselection=0)
frame3_listbox_font.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>')
frame3_listbox_font.pack()
Button(frame3_frame_list, text='Uniform Font').pack(pady=20, anchor='center')

frame3_frame_font_title = Frame(Mafenetre, bg='blue')
frame3_frame_font_label = Frame(Mafenetre, bg='cyan')
frame3_frame_font_combobox = Frame(Mafenetre, bg='yellow')
frame3_frame_font_title.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E + N)
frame3_frame_font_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N + W + E + S)
frame3_frame_font_combobox.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)

Label(frame3_frame_font_title, text="Font Family").pack(padx=20, pady=20)
Label(frame3_frame_font_label, text="Family:").pack(padx=15, pady=10, anchor='nw')
Label(frame3_frame_font_label, text="Style:").pack(padx=15, pady=10, anchor='nw')
Label(frame3_frame_font_label, text="Size:").pack(padx=15, pady=10, anchor='nw')
Label(frame3_frame_font_label, text="Color:").pack(padx=15, pady=18, anchor='nw')

fontVar = StringVar()
fontStyleVar = StringVar()
frame3_combobox_font = ttk.Combobox(frame3_frame_font_combobox, textvariable=fontVar)
frame3_combobox_font['values'] = ('Arial', 'Comic', 'Times New Roman')

frame3_combobox_font.current(1)
frame3_combobox_font.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
frame3_combobox_font.pack(pady=10, anchor='w')

frame3_combobox_font_style = ttk.Combobox(frame3_frame_font_combobox, textvariable=fontStyleVar)
frame3_combobox_font_style['values'] = ('Bold', 'Italic')

frame3_combobox_font_style.current(1)
frame3_combobox_font_style.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
frame3_combobox_font_style.pack(pady=10, anchor='w')

Spinbox(frame3_frame_font_combobox, from_=2, to=300).pack(pady=10, anchor='w')
Button(frame3_frame_font_combobox, text='Font Color').pack(pady=10, anchor='center')


Mafenetre.mainloop()
```

[image]

Thank you for your time and possible answer(s).

Comment: Try to [add line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JShEz.png) `Mafenetre.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)` into your code. If your really prefer `grid`, then read [this](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) (and especially a "Handling Resize" section), otherwise - use a `pack`.

Comment: Thank you, it works great, in my case I just need to use method rowconfigure() for `frame3_root` !

Answer (score 0):

The space that is immediately below the blue "Font Family" frame is space that has been allocated to the "Font Family" label. `frame3_frame_font_title` does not "stick" to the bottom of it's space. Since it's not tall enough to fill its space, that space goes unused.

You can see this by setting the sticky for `frame3_frame_font_title` to be `W + E + N + S` (or the much easier to read and type literal string `"wens"`. Whether that's the solution or not I can't say, since I don't know exactly what the end result should look like.

The space that is below the yellow and cyan frames is row 2 of the root window, which doesn't have anything in the right-most column. The reason it is row 2 is because `frame3_frame_list` has a `rowspan` of 3, meaning it occupies rows 0, 1, and 2.

### How to solve the problem

You didn't explain exactly what look you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to give a concrete suggestion. My recommendation is to start over, and try to solve one problem at a time.

For example, start with an empty window. Add six frames - three rows by two columns. Get those all to be exactly like you want them. Remember to configure the weights of the rows and columns so that they grow and shrink appropriately when you resize the window.

Once you have that, you can start adding in the widgets for one of those areas. For example, Add just the "Elements" label, and make sure it looks right. Then add the "Font Family" label, and so on.